# Creating Users and Permissions in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions

I have some users in my site for example

```
User1
User2
User3
```

Now I have created a site and my requirement is that `User1` is the super user that could add,delete, edit and view documents.`User2` could just add and view documents and `User3` could only view those items.

How could this be done in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 0):

This is simple and the way is the same in all SharePoint versions. You use SharePoint groups to manage permissions for users. In each site you'll find groups, and each group has a different set of permissions. For example the Owners group, which has full control permissions level on your site, would be your choice for let's say user1. You would use Visitors group, which has read permission level, for users who must have read only permission on the site (user3). Finally use Members group which has contribute permission level to edit content on the site (user2). I suggest you read more about this.

Check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q1V9p9wceAU